# QMediaPlayer - playing youtube music

Tags: qt, qmediaplayer

Qt5 introduced `QMediaPlayer` but it can't play youtube link (I want only music). What I found is that in Qt 4.8 (phonon) it could but in Qt5 I get error:

> Missing decoder for 'text/html'. GStreamer has no plugin for it

It is pure translation from Polish output in Qt creator. Is it a matter of GStreamer plugin or should I download HTML content, find direct link to media and play it? Any idea?

Code:

```
mMediaPlayer.setMedia(QUrl("http://youtu.be/wVvoQIdD80U"));
mMediaPlayer.play();
```

Comment: How should  `QMediaPlayer` know that it shall play the video contained in an webpage? You must of course specify the direct address of the media file instead of a HTML page which somehow references it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to youtube video is link to web page, that contain link to media. First off all you need to extract this URL from web page than handle this URL.

You may look, how to do this in [Qt-YouTube project on GitHub](https://github.com/skhaz/qt-youtube/blob/master/YouTubeDataHandler.cpp).